# using absolute value symbol in mhchem \ce environment

Tags: mhchem

I am trying to use the absolute value symbol in the `\ce{}` environment provided by the `mhchem` package, but the value is converted to a horizontal line. Is there a way to escape the symbol so that it will be interpreted literally?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{A_{|a|}B_{b} <=>}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I'd simply use math mode: `\ce{A_$|a|$B_$b$ <=>}`. Since a, b are variables, they are not supposed to be upright characters anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just load the `fontenc` package with `T1` encoding (which is a good thing most of the times when using pdflatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{A_{|a|}B_{b} <=>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I've used version 4 in the example but the answer holds for version 3 as well.

---

Personally I'd also use math mode for the variables and I'd probably define a command like `\abs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}

\ce{A_{$\abs{a}$}B_{$b$} <=>}

\end{document}
```